# How to get price to appear in a <table>?

Tags: product, price, template, product-view, html

For alignment purposes, I'd like to insert price into a table. My other attributes are showing within the table but price goes out completely even though the code is within the table.
[image]

**Code**

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $this->__('MSRP: ') ?></td>
<td><span style="text-decoration:line-through;"><?php echo mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getMsrp(),true,false); ?> </span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $this->__('Price: ') ?></td>
<td><?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**How can price be displayed in a table?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an open  tag on the first , which closes on the second :

This should be the correct code:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $this->__('MSRP: ') ?></td>
<td><span style="text-decoration:line-through;"><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getMsrp(),true,false); ?> </span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $this->__('Price: ') ?></td>
<td><?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You are correct that I had made a mistake(+1 for pointing it out.), I have corrected it but the problem is still occurring.

Comment: Can you post the link of the site(use an URL shortner so your site doesn't show on stackexchange)?

Comment: It's not the best way, but you can replace $this->getTierPriceHtml() with Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getFinalPrice(),true,false)

Comment: Beautiful it's working within the table but the price is still showing up lower on the page despite the code being removed. Any idea?

Comment: You need to remove it. Find something like this $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') and comment it out.

Comment: Excellent, wish I could give you another +1 for that. Really appreciate the assistance. Learning new things every day here! BTW: You may want to edit your post to reflect this information. I searched and searched and couldn't find anything. Having it in your official answer will help someone in the future without having to dig through all this. SR

Answer (score 1):

I think putting this in a table is not the right way, imo, only tabular data should be placed in a table. If I were you, Id use some CSS to fix the alignments. How about that?

Comment: CSS is an option, but the table just makes it so much easier. Anyway Klevis came up with an acceptable solution. Thanks for posting.